# Error installing perl module

Tags: macos, perl, cpan

Trying to install a  a Perl Module from CPAN,

Using the commands

```
 get DBD::mysql
 make DBD::mysql`
```

Its successful until I reach I do these commands.

```
test DBD::mysql`
```

and

```
 install DBD::mysql`
```

I get this error

```
#   Failed test 'use DBD::mysql;'

FAILED--Further testing stopped: Unable to load DBD::mysql
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
MICHIELB/DBD-mysql-4.041.tar.gz
/usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
```

Really confused about what to do to get the module to install and get the module functioning.

Any ideas ?

Comment: which osx are you using?

Comment: You need to post the actual test failures, this is output on screen.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** Agreeing with comments by @stevieb, I change the order of my recommendations, manual install and cpanm first, THEN careful force install.

Try installing it manually:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/MI/MICHIELB/DBD-mysql-4.041.tar.gz
tar zxvf DBD-mysql-4.041.tar.gz
cd DBD-mysql-4.041
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install
```

At best, you should be able to install the module.
At the very least, you should have details about why it did not install. You could then add these details to your original post and get more enlightened answers.

Another solution could be to use cpanminus. I don't know why: sometimes, a module that wouldn't install with CPAN would with cpanminus.

If you don't have cpanminus :

```
cpan -i App::cpanminus
```

then

```
cpanm -i DBD::mysql
```

If nothing works and the errors from the test don't seem too important, try to force the install.

in the CPAN shell :

```
force install DBD::mysql
```

Comment: It would be prudent to find out which test is failing and why before blindly force installing, especially for software that will be manipulating data (DB backend in this case), so I'd recommend the `cpan` and `cpanm` commands along with the manual build before recommending force.

Comment: Agreed. I edited the answer accordingly. Though if it is installed on osx it is probably not production.

Comment: Its failing here  `'Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00base.t .............................. 1/6 Bailout called.  Further testing stopped:  Unable to load DBD::mysql

#   Failed test 'use DBD::mysql;'
#   at t/00base.t line 15.`